# Writing et cetera as etc. in German?

Tags: abbreviation

In English language we write the abbreviation for et cetera as etc., Can we use the etc. in German? If not what abbreviation could be used for et cetera.

Comment: Sure you can, that's used very often.

Comment: Why not take a look at a [dictionary](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/etc_) before posting?

Comment: Note that the original wording is *et cetera* (with a space), Latin for *and others*.

Comment: Note also that the *etc.* needs to be followed by a dot (period). Likewise in *usw.* (*und so weiter*) and *ggf.* (*gegebenenfalls*) and *z.B.* (*zum Beispiel*).

Comment: @DavidVogt, Thank you for your advice. I didn't know, that I could use dictionary instead of this platform.

Comment: @XeoffBaloch   The idea of this forum is that people first try with reasonable effort to find answers by using the usual means (like dictionaries), and post a question here when things are still not clear. The question would include a short description of efforts done so far, and of doubts about the answers found.

Comment: "und so weiter"m abgekürzt als "usw."

Comment: @Christian The main idea is that SE sites aren't _"forums"_ at all, but question and answer like FAQs.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I observed that, It is possible to use etc. However, in German writing few more words are also used for etc.

The words are as followed.

```
etc. pp (and so on and so forth) 

und so weiter or usw (and so on) 

und so weiter, und so fort"
```

Sometime in speaking you may find people using "und und und"

Comment: An interesting question is how you would write the *und und und*. Theoretically you should separate the words by commas (*und, und, und*) but this doesn't feel good in my opinion because the comma is just too strong a separator compared to how it is usually pronounced. I am frequently transcribing interviews for research purposes, and *und und und* appears quite often there. I spell it *und-und-und* in these cases, i.e. treating it as a single word. Example: "*Das hat zu Problemen mit der Geschäftsführung, geführt, zu Ärger mit den Kunden, und-und-und.*" But this is just my private solution.